# Difference between concrete builder and builder?

Tags: builder, software-design, builder-pattern

Builder design pattern has four principle include concrete builder and builder. What is the difference between concrete builder and builder?

Answer (score 0):

I preusume you are referring to this picture (borrowed from Wikipedia):

[image: builder pattern]

`Builder` would just be the **interface** (meaning no implementation) and `ConcreteBuilder` is the implemenation of that interface. `ConcreteBuilder` would handle the creation of other objects

Example:

```cs
// Builder interface
public interface ICarBuilder
{
    void SetColour(string colour); // no implementation
}

// ConcreteBuilder implementation
public class CarBuilder: ICarBuilder
{
    private Car _car;

    public CarBuilder()
    {
        this._car = new Car();
    }

    // implementation
    public void SetColour(string colour)
    {
        this._car.Colour = colour;
    }
}
```